# How to insert and check the check boxes in grid view in c#?

Tags: c#, gridview, checkbox

I can insert check box using this code.
Here is my code :

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn CBColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        CBColumn.HeaderText = "SEL";
        CBColumn.FalseValue = "0";
        CBColumn.TrueValue = "1";
        datagridInfoOrg.Columns.Insert(0, CBColumn);
```

But, I am not able to check the check boxes.

Comment: did you try CBColumn.ReadOnly = false?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me.. Are you setting anything else apart from this code?
Try adding

```
 CBColumn.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
```

OR removing falseValue and trueValue